# How can I get data from a file using Flex/Bison and store it into a structure data of other class?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I want Flex and Bison for parsing a file that contains data which I need to store in data structures that other class contains. The file is structured according to a grammar.

The question is if it's possible to use Flex and Bison for getting data from a file that other class needs, in my case called `Player`: the program reads the file and when it detects a certain token the program stores it into a data structure of `Player`, for example, `std::vector<std::string>`, and if there is an error, throw an exception.

I don't know if it's possible to instance a supposed object of the class Bison and, call from the constructor of `Player` the function `yyparse(&v_strings)` using `%parse-param` in Bison. Then, I could code actions associated to a rule and register the token I want into the array I have passed by reference in `yyparse(&v_strings)`.

I give an example of a piece of my grammar if it was necessary and a context:

#### Lexical rules:

```
    TIME [0-9]+
    DIRECTION UR|DR|DL|UL|U|D|L|R
    ACTION A|J|M

    %%

    {TIME}      {printf("TIME");      return (TIME);}
    {DIRECTION} {printf("DIRECTION"); return (DIRECTION);}
    {ACTION}    {printf("ACTION");    return (ACTION);}
    "~"         {printf("RELEASED");  return (RELEASED);}
    "+"         {printf("PLUS_OP");   return (PLUS_OP);}
    "*"         {printf("COMB_OP");   return (COMB_OP);}
```

#### Grammar rules:

```
    command : list_move PLUS_OP list_action
            | list_move COMB_OP list_action
            | list_move list_action
            | list_move
            | list_action
            ;

    list_move:  move list_move_prm
                ;

    list_move_prm:  move
                  | move list_move_prm
                  | ";"
                  ;

    list_action:  ACTION list_action_prm
                  ;

    list_action_prm:  PLUS_OP ACTION list_action_prm
                    | COMB_OP ACTION list_action_prm
                    | ACTION list_action_prm
                    | ";" //epsilon
                    ;

    move: TIME RELEASED DIRECTION
        | RELEASED DIRECTION
        | DIRECTION
        ;
```

Comment: Yes, passing an instance of the object like that is basically the strategy. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Ehm I just can't figure out the question. Can you please rephrase that ?

Comment: @rici but, how can I call `yyparse(v_vector)` from other class? I think I need an instance of supposed class `Bison` or something like that.
I couldn't tried it because of it. I read manuals and tutorials but it was not clear to me.

Comment: @ArneJ I have a class, for example called `Player`. From it's constructor I want to call to function `yyparse(v_vector)`, being v_vector `std::vector<std::string>` and a member of `Player`. When a certain `Token` is detected I want to store it into the `vector`. The problem is I don't know how to call `yyparse(v_vector)` from the constructor of the class `Player` and how to instance an object of Bison for calling this function.

Comment: @briko: if you need a parser object, you just define one like any other object; parser objects aren't special. That's if you use Bison's C++ API. Of course, you can use the traditional API, which produces a global function instead; that's easier, but some people don't like it because it's not very C++-like.

Comment: @briko: by the way, I personally think that constructors should not throw exceptions; I would probably do the work in a member function. (Other people disagree so don't take that as gospel.) Also, Bison-generated parser objects are reusable, which can be slightly more efficient if you are parsing many inputs.